# cocoon gem attributes not saving when creating new recipe

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, cocoon-gem

In week 3 of mackenziechild-recipe_box, I am experiencing some issues with Cocoon. I have devise installed, as well, and my `ingredients` and `directions` attributes are not being saved when I create a new `Recipe`. But when I update an existing `Recipe`, everything is fine. The error message is:

> Ingredients recipe must exist, directions recipe must exist

What am I doing wrong? I am using rails 5

**app/models/recipe.rb**

```
class Recipe < ApplicationRecord
  validates :title, :description, :image, presence: true
  has_attached_file :image, styles: { medium: "400x400#" }
  validates_attachment_content_type :image, content_type: /\Aimage\/.*\Z/
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :ingredients
  has_many :directions
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :ingredients, :reject_if => :all_blank, :allow_destroy => true
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :directions, :reject_if => :all_blank, :allow_destroy => true
end
```

**app/controllers/recipes_controller.rb**

```
def new
  @recipe = Recipe.new
  @recipe = current_user.recipes.build
end

def create
  @recipe = Recipe.new(recipe_params)
  @recipe = current_user.recipes.build(recipe_params)
  if @recipe.save
    # show a success flash message and redirect to the recipe show page
    flash[:success] = 'New recipe created successfully'
    redirect_to @recipe
  else
    # show fail flash message and render to new page for another shot at creating a recipe
    flash[:danger] = 'New recipe failed to save, try again'
    render 'new'
  end
end

def update
  if @recipe.update(recipe_params)
    # display a success flash and redirect to recipe show page
    flash[:success] = 'Recipe updated successfully'
    redirect_to @recipe
  else
    # display an alert flash and remain on edit page
    flash[:danger] = 'Recipe failed to update, try again'
    render 'edit'
  end
end

private

def recipe_params
  params.require(:recipe).permit(:title, :description, :image,
    directions_attributes: [:id, :step, :_destroy],
    ingredients_attributes: [:id, :name, :_destroy])
end

def recipe_link
  @recipe = Recipe.find(params[:id])
end
```

**app/views/recipes/_ingredient_fields.html.haml** partial

```
.form-inline.clearfix
.nested-fields
    = f.input :name, input_html: { class: 'form-input form-control' }
    = link_to_remove_association 'Remove', f, class: 'form-button btn btn-default'
```

**app/views/recipes/_direction_fields.html.haml** partial

```
.form-inline.clearfix
.nested-fields
    = f.input :step, input_html: { class: 'form-input form-control' }
    = link_to_remove_association 'Remove', f, class: 'form-button btn btn-default'
```

Comment: On what line do you get that error? Did adding the `inverse_of` actually solved anything (because I have never had to do to that). In your `create` you create the `@recipe` twice --> did you notice that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> But when I update an existing `Recipe`, everything is fine.

That's your answer. When you're creating a new recipe, you don't have the recipe object, because it's in the server memory. But when you're updating it, the recipe object is persisted.

That's why you're getting the `Ingredients recipe must exist` and `directions recipe must exist` error.

To fix that you have to add the `inverse_of` in the associations.

```
class Recipe
  has_many :ingredients, inverse_of: :recipe
  has_many :directions, inverse_of: :recipe

class Ingredient
  belongs_to :recipe, inverse_of: :ingredients

class Direction
  belongs_to :recipe, inverse_of: :directions
```

When you include the `inverse_of`, Rails now knows about those associations and will "match" them in memory.

More about `inverse_of`:

- http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html
- http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html

Comment: This work, thanks. I need to dive into the inverse_of