# Rails nested forms w/ Cocoon gem, rejecting association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nested-forms, model-associations, cocoon-gem

A recipe has many ingredients and directions, each belongs to a recipe. My `views/new.html.haml` renders a `_form` partial, which renders the nested partials. It rejects upon submission saying that the required nested elements don't exist. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong or missing. I've gone over the code and cocoon docs repeatedly. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

## models/recipe.rb

```
has_many :ingredients
has_many :directions

accepts_nested_attributes_for :ingredients, reject_if: :all_blank, allow_destroy: true
accepts_nested_attributes_for :directions, reject_if: :all_blank, allow_destroy: true
```

Using simple_form gem in a `_form.html.haml` partial

```
        %h3 Ingredients
        #ingredients
          = f.simple_fields_for :ingredients do |ingredient|
            = render 'ingredient_fields', f: ingredient
          .links
            = link_to_add_association 'Add Ingredient', f, :ingredients

        %h3 Directions
        #directions
          = f.simple_fields_for :directions do |direction|
            = render 'direction_fields', f: direction
          .links
            = link_to_add_association 'Add Step', f, :directions

  = f.button :submit
```

This links to a partial for each nested element, ingredients and directions...

## views/recipes/_direction_fields.html.haml

```
.nested-fields
  = f.input :step, input_html: { class: 'form-input form-control' }
  = link_to_remove_association "Remove Step", f, class: 'btn btn-default form-button'
```

## views/recipes/_ingredient_fields.html.haml

```
.nested-fields
  = f.input :name, input_html: { class: "form-input form-control" }
  = link_to_remove_association "Remove", f, class: "form-button btn btn-default"
```

When I attempt to submit a new recipe with directions and ingredients I get a rollback and flash notice reading...

> 2 Prevented this recipe from saving
>
> Ingredients recipe must exist Directions recipe must exist

Comment: I am guessing you have a validation in `Ingredient` and `Direction` that the recipe must exist, something like `validates_presence_of :recipe`. How do you save? I think it could work if you check for the presence of `:recipe_id` (because in general they are all saved together).

Comment: It doesn't work even if I take all the validations out.

Answer (score 1):

This solved my issue. [cocoon gem attributes not saving when creating new recipe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37796204/cocoon-gem-attributes-not-saving-when-creating-new-recipe)

Rails 5 now requires you to declare `inverse_of` in the model associations.